# Probability about combinatorics

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, permutations

I came across these 2 problem about combinatorics which I originally thought they were basically the same. However, the solution key told me otherwise.

Question 1
[image: Q1]

Question 2
[image: Q2]

My answer to Q1 is 0.18 which is correct, I then use the same way to solve Q2, where the solution is 0.2105. I wonder why there is such difference?

Comment: You must provide more detail on the way you got these expressions, because that's more important than the answer. So show your working

Comment: Without doing any calculations, it seems to me that the second problem would be about choosing three different items, while the first problem has the potential to choose the same model and color of car multiple times.

Comment: @MatthewDaly, yes, that would be the case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, each customer can choose any of the $20$ cars. The question explicitly says that "at least three units of each car are available", which means that several customers can choose the same (typa-color) combination of car. So the probability is

$$\frac{5\cdot 4}{20}\cdot\frac{4\cdot 3}{20}\cdot\frac{3\cdot 2}{20}=\frac{72}{400}=0.18$$

In the second case, each item is only available once, so three *different* items are chosen. The probability is

$$\frac{5\cdot 4}{20}\cdot\frac{4\cdot 3}{19}\cdot\frac{3\cdot 2}{18}=\frac{72}{342}\approx 0.2105$$

Comment: loud and clear!!!

Comment: Why the car lot is composed by $20$ elements?

Comment: @the_candyman there are 4 types of car and 5 colors of car, so there are 20 different cars.

Comment: The OP said that "At least 3 cars of each type and color are available". Therefore, this is also possible with less than $20$ cars. For example with $15$ cars it is possible.

Comment: @the_candyman the question in the book is not very precisely written, but I understand that "at least 3 cars of each (type+color) combination are available", i.e., there are at least 60 cars. This is consistent with the provided solution.

Comment: I agree that it is not very precisely written. Good answer +1.